# Web Api POST inserted Data without Id created

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am learning to pass data to Web API. I created A web Api Project and I am using Ado.Net Entities DataModel base On DataBase First Approach for this project and I encountered a problem as described below.

I created a Controller.
Here I use `[FromBody]` to receive the JSON data:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository()

    [HttpPost]
    public void PostContact([FromBody] Customer contact)
    {
        repository.Add(contact);
    }
  
    ...
}
```

I'm using the repository pattern to handle CRUD.
Here are my classes:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
    Customer GetById(int CustId);
    int Update(Customer Cust);
    void Add(Customer Cust);
    void Delete(int CustId);
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    // using Ado.net Entities
    MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities();

    public void Add(Customer contact)
    {       
        var addedContact = ctx.Customers.Add(contact);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the table in SQL Server:

```
CustId              int
CustomerName        nvarchar(50)
CustomerPassword    nvarchar(50)
CustomerEmailAddr   nvarchar(100)
CustomerMobileNo    nvarchar(20)
CreatedOn           DateTime       (only this allows Nulls)
```

My Web API is ok when I do a `GetById` for the first record manually inserted into the table thru SSMS.  I used Fiddler to do testing for a 2nd customer.

1. I used POST selection in Fiddler
2. I added

   ```
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Type : application/json
   ```
3. I added this JSON data string in the request-body section for post

   ```
   {
     "CustomerName": "David2",
     "CustomerPassword": "12345672",
     "CustomerEmailAddr": "123,Motoway ",
     "CustomerMobileNo": "968772322",
     "CreatedOn": "04/25/2017"
   }
   ```

Problem when doing a POST in Fiddler:

There is no `CustID` generated.  There is a new row with `CustID 0`
The table only shows the rest of the data without `CustId` (`CustId 0`)

**Update**

I have set `PrimaryKey` for `CustId`, and set up these in properties:

```
Is Identity: yes, 
Identity Increment: 1 
Identity Seed: 1
```

When I execute the POST I get this error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

**Update:**

```
This is the class name inside the Edmx:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public partial class Customer
    {      

        public int CustId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerPassword { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmailAddr { get; set; }
        public string CustomerMobileNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hello can you please share save operation code so I can see in detail and table script as well need to check is it correct or may need some changes!

Comment: The Save Operation is provided by Ado.net Entities DataModel and EntityFramework v6 when I created the Web api project base on Database First Approach. That is Method I used.

Comment: Yes I understand that entity framework has it's function to add the object means new record in table but how you are saving it that I want to see either make clone or viewmodel of the same table class or directly save the coming object of a class? whatever code please provide in the question so I can help you exactly with issue.

Comment: please see the update.  The class model which is inside the edmx.

Comment: Dear I am asking about the save operation not the class body, post the code that your api post method where you are saving the details.

Comment: are you asking this : var addedContact = ctx.Customers.Add(contact);
ctx.SaveChanges(); This is from EntityFx. I dont write any code  Or Are you asking a file inside edmx? or code in the Controller? I used Fiddler to post the Json data string which intercept by CustomerController above. Then I use CustomerRepository to implement the ICustomerInterface :Add,then I use the Add method from the EntityFx to insert record. I dont use Asp.net MVC form to post.

Comment: yes I want to know about this var addedContact = ctx.Customers.Add(contact); how you get this from the post method directly from the client side controller or from the view (jquery ajax post)?

Comment: just one step needed to solve your problem please share your passing value code or just say it how you pass that Customer object either using controller side or using ajax!

Answer (score 1):

Is CustId is primary key and auto increment? if not then make CustId primary key with auto increment

Comment: oops....! my fault.  u are right. I tried to set Is identity , I got this msg: Saving Changes is not permitted.  Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Funny thing happened. I deleted the table and recreated one. Now , there is nothing inserted! Something wrong with my code?

Comment: I have set primaryKey for CustId, and set up these in properties: Is Identity yes, Identity Increment 1  Identity Seed 1.  When I execute the post. I got this errorMsg : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: @MilkBottle because your table's primary key (CustId) is not set auto increment

Comment: I did this to CustId in SSMS:
 
I have set primaryKey for CustId, and set up these in properties: Is Identity yes, Identity Increment 1 Identity Seed 1. Please advise if this is wrong.

Comment: please provide code in detail for  save/add function so that i can find actually problem.

Comment: I dont write the code for Save, I used the one from the entityFx. I think you mean the Asp.net MVC form I used to post and save data. I did not use the Asp.net MVC form to post.